# How to hide a menu using $document.on in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable-**isTelephoneMenuOpen** that makes my menu Open.
Now on click on anywhere else in window I want to make it disappear.
I tried this code but Its not working.Please help

```js
  $document.on('click', function (event) {
      if (this.isTelephoneMenuOpen = true) {
           console.log("close menu");
           this.isTelephoneMenuOpen = false;
           // return $document.off('click', event);
      }
});
```

Comment: Please note that everything is in the same controller

Comment: This is not how we use AngularJS. Check `ng-show`, `ng-if` and `ng-click`

Comment: Also notice that your condition is ASSIGNING the value, not comparing it. It will ALWAYS evaluate to `true`

Comment: @casraf:Thanks .
       $document.on('click', function (event) {
            if (self.isTelephoneMenuOpen == true) {
                console.log("close menu");
                self.isTelephoneMenuOpen = false;
                 console.log("self val --->"+ self.isTelephoneMenuOpen);
                  console.log("this val --->"+ this.isTelephoneMenuOpen);
                 
                //return $document.off('click', event);
            }

        });


I corrected the code.Its working ...But when I hover to the Menu item list disappears.

Comment: @Weedoze:Thanks for suggestion.But how to make that variable false when a user click anywhere else in the window and without using directive ?

Comment: @pourushsinghgaur Dont use `if(myBoolean == true)` just say `if(myBoolean)`

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword inside event handlers binds to the element emitting the event, not the `this` context of the parent function. Explicitly bind the parent `this` context to a variable.

```
  var $ctrl = this;

  $document.on('click', menuClickHandler);

  this.$onDestroy = function() {
      $document.off('click', menuClickHandler);
  };

  function menuClickHandler(event) {
      if ($ctrl.isTelephoneMenuOpen) {
           console.log("close menu");
           $ctrl.isTelephoneMenuOpen = false;
           $rootScope.$apply();
      }
  }
```

Click events come from outside the AngularJS framework. Use $apply to initiate an AngularJS digest cycle to update the DOM.

[image]

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide (v1.1) - Concepts - Runtime](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide/concepts#runtime).

Comment: Very nice explanation, one remark though: digesting the scope in which the binding is to be re-evaluated is much better (faster) then forcing a complete digest on all elements using `$rootScope.$apply()`.

Comment: I think you are confusing `$digest` with `$apply`. `$apply` executes an expression function and then initiates a `root.$digest`. It really doesn't matter from which scope it is started.

Comment: My point is that it is always better to call `$digest` in the current scope instead of calling it in root, which `$apply` does.